# panel in 14.04 is not fully transparent

Tags: unity, panel, gnome-panel

There are two images just to show what I mean. In 12.04 top panel was 100% transparent. See the picture below.

12.04
[image: Panel in 12.04]

In 14.04 the settings are the same, but there is no 100% transparency. See the picture below

14.04
[image: Panel in 14.04]

Is that some kind of bug? How can be fixed?

Regards,

Comment: it is unity ? or gnome

Comment: It is Unity, not gnome. From Ubuntu Tweak (and in Compiz) is set to be fully transparent. There is some transparency (let's say 50%) and as I can see it is "blur".

Answer (score -1):

I have been wondering about this too, so far the only way I have been able to find to get a fully transparent panel in 14.04 is with this theme:
http://satya164.deviantart.com/art/Gnome-Shell-Elegance-Colors-305966388